# Image in bootstrap popover is not contained in a frame

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I use bootstrap popover.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'right',
        content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';}
});
});
</script>
```

But big images are not contained in a frame as you can see in an image below.

How can I fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: in your CSS
    .popover { width: %framewidth%px; } and make sure to adjust max-width with the same value

Comment: I already tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that I need to change max-width.

```
.popover{
    max-width: 500px;
}
```